# How to deserialize arrays inside arrays on C# using newtonsoft

Tags: c#, json.net

I want to deserialize this JSON data. How can I deserialize it to a C# class object or list?

```
[  
   2074,
   [  
      0,
      0,
      0,
      1,
      0,
      0,
      0
   ],
   0,
   [  
      {  
         "886":[  
            "Anna Bay"
         ],
         "3971":[  
            "Dmitry Khraponenkov"
         ]
      },
      [  
         3971,
         886
      ]
   ]
]
```

I need to parse out the names.

I tried this, but this is a very different thing: [newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/DeserializeCollection.htm](http://newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/DeserializeCollection.htm)

Comment: Please provide a [mcve] of what you have tried.

Comment: i tried this but this is very different thing. https://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/DeserializeCollection.htm

Comment: Please put it in your post

Comment: done @ArtemisFowl

Comment: What object/list are you trying to deserialize this into now?  What exactly does each part of the JSON data represent?

Comment: Well you've linked to a documentation page that tries to deserialize to a list of strings. Your JSON doesn't represent a list of strings. Did you try deserializing to a `List<object>`? What happened with whatever you *did* try?

Answer (score 1):

Without knowing more about what exactly this data represents or what class structure you would ideally want to deserialize it into, it is difficult to provide useful advice.  But, if I take your question literally as, "here's some JSON with mixed data types; how do I extract the names from it?", then you can solve that problem using Json.Net's [LINQ-to-JSON API](https://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/LINQtoJSON.htm):

```
string json = @"[ 2074, [ 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0 ], 0, [{ ""886"": [ ""Anna Bay"" ], ""3971"": [ ""Dmitry Khraponenkov"" ] }, [ 3971, 886 ] ] ]";

List<string> names = JArray.Parse(json)
    .Descendants()
    .OfType<JProperty>()
    .SelectMany(p => p.Value, (p, t) => (string)t)
    .ToList();

Console.WriteLine(string.Join(Environment.NewLine, names));
```

Fiddle: https://dotnetfiddle.net/EJOKeW

Answer (score 0):

### A note about JSON

JSON is used to represent a data structure. The data contained is often a collection of name-value pairs. Pairing each value with a name allows a consumer to work with the JSON with no prior knowledge of the data or data structure. As Brian points out in the comments below, JSON can also be a collection of values, but this puts the burden of interpreting those values on the consumer.

### Back to your question

Most of your values don't have names, which makes it difficult to deserialize to a C# class object.

If you are able to modify the JSON, please do so and give each value a name.

If you are not able to modify the JSON, then you may just want to parse the string.

---

To learn more about JSON, visit: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/JavaScript/Objects/JSON

Comment: I have to disagree.  JSON is not "by definition a collection of name-value pairs".  That is only *one* component of JSON.  JSON also consists of arrays and simple values.  (See [JSON.org](http://www.json.org/).)  In fact, you can have perfectly valid JSON that contains no name-value pairs at all, for example `["foo", "bar", "baz"]`.  Granted, it is difficult to deserialize mixed data such as the OP's into a class structure, but it can be done using one or more custom JsonConverters, so long as we know how the data should be mapped (which the OP has not bothered to explain to us).

Comment: @BrianRogers You're right. My original definition was too strict. I've updated my answer. Thanks for the feedback.